# Nesting a Label inside a ListView in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I am pretty new to WPF and I have tried figuring out how to add a Label appear inside a the following ListView which shows the number of Items currently in the ListView.  I've given the ListView padding on the top to make room for the Label.

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,40,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatasetCode}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of putting the `Label` inside the `ListView`? If you want a reusable solution, why don't you author a `UserControl` that combines a `Label` and `ListView` in a single component? You might be able to hack something together overriding the default `ListView.Template` but IME that's usually more of a pain than it's worth for scenarios like this. Please explain more precisely why the `Label` _has_ to be part of the `ListView`. Please also provide a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried already, with a clear explanation of what specific problem you had getting that to work.

Comment: I guess this is doable, please post some screenshot of expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ListBoxCount output]

1. Edit the `Template` of `ListBox`. You can do this by Right-Clicking the `ListBox` in the `Document outline` section. And add your `Label` as below.

   ```
   ...
   <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
       <StackPanel>
           <Label uc:Window2.CountFor="False" />
           <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
   ...
   ```
2. I have written an attached property `CountFor` . Code is give below :

   ```
       #region CountFor attached property


       public static bool GetCountFor(DependencyObject obj)
       {
           return (bool)obj.GetValue(CountForProperty);
       }

       public static void SetCountFor(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
       {
           obj.SetValue(CountForProperty, value);
       }

       // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CountFor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
       public static readonly DependencyProperty CountForProperty =
           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CountFor", typeof(bool), typeof(Window2), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(GetCountForChanged)));

       private static void GetCountForChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if ((bool)e.NewValue == false) return;

           Label lbl = (Label)d;
           lbl.Loaded += (o, args) =>
           {
               DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(lbl);
               while (parent.GetType() != typeof(ListBox))
                   parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

               ListBox lb = (ListBox)parent;

               ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lb.ItemsSource);
               lbl.Content = "Number of items = " + ((ListCollectionView)view).Count;

               view.CollectionChanged += (col, colargs) =>
               {

                   lbl.Content = "Number of items = " + ((ListCollectionView)col).Count;

                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((ListCollectionView)col).Count.ToString());

               };
           };
       }

       #endregion
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simple, you could just create an int to count the number of items in your label and then assign a new textblock, you could also completely skip the textblock and simply add the int, check this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int testcounter;
        testcounter = listBox.Items.Count;
        TextBlock BlockCounter = new TextBlock();
        BlockCounter.Text = testcounter.ToString();
        listBox.Items.Add(BlockCounter);           
    }
```